# How many tag wiki edits have I made?

Tags: support, badge-progress

I was just looking for the progress on how many tag wiki edits I have made. It used to be down the right hand side of the page when looking at the description of a tag but it appears to have disappeared?

Is there any way I can check this, or restore the progress details?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a tag, you get directed to a "Questions tagged [tag]" page, with an excerpt of the tag wiki and a selection of questions.

This page does not have the Research Assistant badge progress information. You need to click on the "Info" tab, or the "Read more..." link on that page to get there.

- [Questions tagged [badge-progress]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/badge-progress) - no progress information
- [[badge-progress] info page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/badge-progress/info) - progress information